# bintray: Unable to upload files: Maven group, artifact or version defined in the pom file do not match

Tags: android, maven, bintray

I'm trying to create a maven library using Android Studio and bintray but I can't get it working. When I try to upload the lib using `gradle bintrayUpload` I allways get the following error:

```
Could not upload to 'https://api.bintray.com/content/company/maven/company-simplename-lib/simplename/company-simplename-lib/lib/0.0.1/lib-0.0.1.pom': HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [message:Unable to upload files: Maven group, artifact or version defined in the pom file do not match the file path 'company-simplename-lib/lib/0.0.1/lib-0.0.1.pom']
```

This happens when I try to follow the example bintray has in their [github repo](https://github.com/bintray/bintray-examples/blob/master/gradle-bintray-plugin-examples/android-maven-example/build.gradle).

I have changed my library `build.gradle` (not the root) to the following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "1.4"
}

version = '0.0.1'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
    apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName '0.0.1'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'

}

install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        pom.project {
            name 'EasyGoogle'
        description 'A wrapper library for basic functions of Google Play Services APIs'
        url 'https://github.com/googlesamples/easygoogle'
        inceptionYear '2015'

        packaging 'aar'
        groupId 'pub.devrel'
        artifactId 'android-maven-example'
        version '0.1'

        licenses {
            license {
                name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                distribution 'repo'
            }
        }
        scm {
            connection 'https://github.com/googlesamples/easygoogle.git'
            url 'https://github.com/googlesamples/easygoogle'

        }
        developers {
            developer {
                name 'Google'
            }
        }
    }
}

bintray {
    user = project.hasProperty('bintrayUser') ? project.property('bintrayUser') : System.getenv('BINTRAY_USER')
    key = project.hasProperty('bintrayApiKey') ? project.property('bintrayApiKey') : System.getenv('BINTRAY_API_KEY')
    configurations = ['archives']
    pkg {
        repo = 'maven'
        name = 'company-simplename-lib'
        userOrg = user
        licenses = ['Apache-2.0']
        vcsUrl = 'http://example.com/android/company-simplename-lib.git'
        version {
            name = 'simplename'
            desc = 'test build'
            vcsTag = '0.0.1'
            attributes = ['gradle-plugin': 'com.use.less:com.use.less.gradle:gradle-useless-plugin']
        }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.4'
}
```

Is someone able to see what I'm doing wrong? Becasue I can't and I can't find any good documentation about this either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working by removing the install part from the gradle file so it looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "1.4"
}

version = '0.0.4'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
    apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName '0.0.4'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
}

bintray {
    user = project.hasProperty('bintrayUser') ? project.property('bintrayUser') : System.getenv('BINTRAY_USER')
    key = project.hasProperty('bintrayApiKey') ? project.property('bintrayApiKey') : System.getenv('BINTRAY_API_KEY')
    configurations = ['archives']
    pkg {
        repo = 'maven'
        name = 'company-simplename-lib'
        userOrg = user
        licenses = ['Apache-2.0']
        vcsUrl = 'http://gitlab.company-servic.es/android/company-simplename-lib.git'
        version {
            name = 'simplename'
            desc = 'test build'
            vcsTag = '0.0.4'
            attributes = ['gradle-plugin': 'com.use.less:com.use.less.gradle:gradle-useless-plugin']
        }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.4'
}
```

Comment: How do you build a POM file if you have no `install` tag?

Comment: This is correct if you have your publishing methods setup correctly and you do not want your module name to be the same as your artifactId

Answer (score 12):

Please go through below blog , it clearly explain everything.

http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en

If you still face issue of uploading pom file then make sure 
**libraryName , artifact and module name should be same**.